# How can i change between UIViewControllers iOS

Tags: ios, ios6, ios7, uiviewcontroller

What i have its this UIViewController herarchy;
A -> B -> C
I need to loop this herarchy from B to C and C to B, but closing and opening a new B in each loop. So, for the first time of the loop, in A i present B, then in B i dismiss B and present C from A, then in C i dimiss C and open B from A, but it only works the first time of the loop, the next time at this last point it dimisses C and B and shows A instead of B, here is my code:

In A:

```
Boxes *B = [[Boxes alloc] initWithLevel:level actualUser:actualUser farm:self];
[self presentModalView:B];
```

In B:

```
CameraViewController *C = [[CameraViewController alloc] initWithBlackboard:1 farm:farmBoard];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:^{
        [A presentModalView:C];
    }];
```

In C:

```
Boxes *B = [[Boxes alloc] initWithLevel:level actualUser:actualUser farm:nil];
            [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:^{
                [A presentModalView:B];
            }];
```

Any idea of why the loops break? or how should i approach this problem?

Comment: You should really have a `RootViewController` managing this interaction instead of these bad cross-references to variables.  For your 'in B' example, you shouldn't instantiate C which you pass off to A and then dismiss B, now B has a reference to C which is really being used in A.  The B reference is just dangling around.

Comment: I already have a RootViewController, but its the first controller to call when my app starts, could i use more than one RootViewController?